# xero - OAuth problems

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, xero-api

Despite following the xero documentation on creating and authorizing an app using postman, when the browser window pops up to login, I get an error 500 and "Error: unauthorized_client : Unknown client or client not enabled".

I have created the app in the developer centre and generated a secret for it as instructed in the documentation.

I am trying to get to generating an access token for use in my application.

Can anyone fill in the tiny bit that I somehow missing ?

Comment: The error suggests to me that it's an incorrect client_id. Lacking that this sounds more like a support question for them. The fact that you got a 500 would actually suggest it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Shonky documentation. Ignore the rubbish about "putting variables in {{}}" as all that did was send {{client_id}} to the identity URL.

In the end I had to paste the actual values into the fields, and it worked like a charm.

That's when I found other discrepancies in the guide. I'll leave those for others to post the fixes to. I have  hours to get back.